# Show that an embedding sends a conjugate transpose to transpose.

Tags: matrices, differential-topology, submanifold, diffeomorphism

Here is the question I am trying to tackle:

Prove that $$\mathbb C \to M_2(\mathbb R),$$ defined by $$x + iy \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} x &  -y \\ y & x\end{pmatrix}$$ defines an embedding. Show also that this embedding sends "conjugate transpose" to "transpose" and multiplication to multiplication.

My definition for embedding is:

> [image]

My definition of a submanifold is:

> [image]
> [image]

My definition of a diffeomorphism is:

> [image]

A hint was given in the book to consider the chart $x: M_2(\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R^4$ given by $$x\Big(\begin{pmatrix} a &  b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix} \Big) = (a,b, a -d, b+c)$$ but I do not know how to use this hint.

Also still I do not how to prove that this is a submanifold, could anyone help me in proving this please?

**EDIT:**

Note that I am asking here about the proof of a submanifold not about the inverse of the function in the other suggested question.

Comment: What does$$x\Big(\begin{pmatrix} x &  -y \\ y & x\end{pmatrix} \Big) = (a,b, a -d, b+c)$$mean?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos sorry I was very sleepy when I wrote this question, I edited my question just now, thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Which textbook is that?

Comment: A short course in differential topology by Bjorn and Dundas

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4442416/finding-the-inverse-of-a-function-from-m-2r/4442480?noredirect=1#comment9302375_4442480 from the same OP.

Comment: @KBS no the question was about the proof of the submanifold not the inverse

Comment: What is the conjugate transpose of a complex number?

Comment: @TedShifrin that was a question of mine also but Jose below his answer said that he will assume that this just means the conjugate and I assumed like him also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If$$x\left(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\right)=(a,b,a-d,b+c),$$ and if$$N=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}x&-y\\y&x\end{bmatrix}\,\middle|\,x,y\in\Bbb R\right\},$$then, for each $M\in M_2(\Bbb R)$, $x(M)\in\Bbb R^2\times\{(0,0)\}$ if and only if $M\in N$. Therefore, $N$ is a submanifold of $M_2(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: Ok, so you are saying that the given hint was a hint actually for showing that it is a submanifold? did I understood you correctly?

Comment: Yes. Actually, that was the only interpretation of the hint that I could think of.

Comment: Also, I think in your typing for the hint you misplaced the negative sign of y

Comment: what about the proof of the remaining part of the question? i.e. it sends conjugate transpose to transpose and multiplication to multiplication. How can I proof this?

Comment: By checking that indeed $x-iy$ is mapped into $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}x&y\\-y&x\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, which is the conjugate transpose of $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}x&-y\\y&x\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, and that $(x_1+iy_1)(x_2+iy_2)(=x_1x_2-y_1y_2+(x_1y_2+x_2y_1)i)$ is mapped into $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}x_1&-y_1\\y_1&x_1\end{smallmatrix}\right].\left[\begin{smallmatrix}x_2&-y_2\\y_2&x_2\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

Comment: Oh really, so the second part is very trivial, so the essence of the question is the proof that it is a submanifold.... I always had hard times in understanding how to prove this definition.

Comment: is the conjugate transpose of $x + iy$ is $x - iy$? (I have only heard the word conjugate transpose for matrices and not for complex numbers)

Comment: I suppose that the author simply meant “conjugate” here.

Comment: Yeah because conjugate transpose is only used for matrices I think

Comment: What is the $U'$ in the definition of submanifold in our case here?

Comment: How can we find the inverse of the given function? how can I show that it is smooth?

Comment: Why your $N$ is different from the range of the given function?The $-y$ is not in the right place

Comment: In my case, $U'=\Bbb R^4$. The inverse is the map$$\begin{bmatrix}x&-y\\y&x\end{bmatrix}\mapsto x+yi.$$The map is smooth because every linear ma is smooth. And I've put the minus sign at the wrong place by mistake. I've edited my answer.

Comment: So we do not need to find the inverse of our matrix to get the inverse of the given function to prove the diffeomorphism?

Comment: Being a diffeomorphism has nothing to do with inverting matrices.

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4442416/finding-the-inverse-of-a-function-from-m-2r/4442480?noredirect=1#comment9302375_4442480 from the same OP.