# finding the inverse of a function from $M_2(R).$

Tags: matrices, inverse, inverse-function, diffeomorphism

I am trying to prove that the given map below is a diffeomorphism and it is pretty clear to me that it is a bijection but I do not know how to show that the inverse of the given map is smooth? in fact I do not know how to find its inverse (on its image), could someone help me in this please?

Prove that $$\mathbb C \to M_2(\mathbb R),$$ $$x + iy \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} x & -y\\
y & x \end{pmatrix}$$
defines an imbedding.

**EDIT:**

Is the inverse can be found by finding the inverse of the given matrix?

**EDIT: 2**

Here is the question I am trying to solve:

Prove that $$\mathbb C \to M_2(\mathbb R),$$ $$x + iy \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} x & -y\\
y & x \end{pmatrix}$$
defines an imbedding. More generally it defines an imbedding $$M_n(\mathbb C) \to M_n(M_2(\mathbb R)) \cong M_{2n}(\mathbb R).$$
Show also that this imbedding sends "conjugate transpose" to "transpose" and "multiplication" to "multiplication".

I am trying to prove that the given map is a diffeomorphism which means that it is a bijection and its inverse is smooth.

Could you please tell me if the question has a typo or no?

Thanks!!

**EDIT:**

> [image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136035/discussion-on-question-by-brain-finding-the-inverse-of-a-function-from-m-2r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the function $f$ as
$$x + iy \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} x & -y\\
y & x \end{pmatrix}$$

and define the set $$\mathcal{M}:=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}x & -y\\y & x\end{bmatrix}:x,y\in\mathbb{R}\right\}.$$

It is immediate to see that $f(\mathbb{C})=\mathcal{M}\subset M_2(\mathbb{R})$.

It is clear then that the map $f$ you are considering is a bijection from $\mathbb C$ to $\mathcal{M}$ and that this function is differentiable.

The function $f$ has then an inverse $g:\mathcal{M}\mapsto\mathbb{C}$ which may take many forms but one simple one is

$$g(M)=e_1^TMe_1+ie_2^TMe_1$$

where $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is the natural basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$. This function is easily seen to be differentiable as it is affine in $M$.

We also have that $f(z^*)=f(z)^T$, $f(z_1+z_2)=f(z_1)+f(z_2)$, and $f(z_1z_2)=f(z_1)f(z_2)$ which can be verified by direct evaluation.

---

Now define the map $h:M_n(\mathbb C)\mapsto M_n(M_2(\mathbb R))$ as

$$h(M) = \sum_{i,j=1}^ne_ie_j^T\otimes f(m_{ij})$$

where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product and $\{e_i\}$ is here the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. This is again an embedding (for the same reasons as for $f$) and we also have that

$$h(M^*)=\sum_{i,j=1}^ne_je_i^T\otimes f(m_{ij})^T= \left(\sum_{i,j=1}^ne_ie_j^T\otimes f(m_{ij})\right)^T=h(M)^T$$

where we have used the fact that the transpose of the sum of the sum of the transpose, and that for two matrices $A$ and $B$, the following equality $(A\otimes B)^T=A^T\otimes B^T$ holds. This shows that the embedding sends "transpose conjugation" to "transpose".

Now, let $C=AB$ for $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb C)$. We have that

$$h(C)=\sum_{i,j=1}^ne_ie_j^T\otimes f(c_{ij}).$$

But $$f(c_{ij})=f\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_{ik}b_{kj}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(a_{ik}b_{kj}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^nf(a_{ik})f(b_{kj}),$$ where we have used the additive and multiplicative properties of $f$ obtained above. Therefore,

$$h(C)=\sum_{i,j=1}^ne_ie_j^T\otimes \left(\sum_{k=1}^nf(a_{ik})f(b_{kj})\right)=\sum_{i,j,k=1}^ne_ie_j^T\otimes (f(a_{ik})f(b_{kj})).$$

If we evaluate now $h(A)h(B)$, we get that

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rcl}
h(A)h(B)&=&\left(\sum_{i,j=1}^ne_ie_j^T\otimes f(a_{ij})\right)\left(\sum_{i,j=1}^ne_ie_j^T\otimes f(b_{ij})\right)\\
%
&=&\sum_{i,j,k,\ell=1}^n\left(e_ie_k^T\otimes f(a_{ik})\right)\left(e_\ell e_j^T\otimes f(b_{\ell j})\right)\\
%
&=&\sum_{i,j,k,\ell=1}^n\left(e_ie_k^Te_\ell e_j^T\right)\otimes\left(f(a_{ik})f(b_{\ell j})\right)\\
%
&=&\sum_{i,j,k=1}^ne_ie_j^T\otimes\left(f(a_{ik})f(b_{kj})\right)\\
&=&h(AB)
\end{array}
\end{equation}

This, finally, proves that this embedding sends "multiplication" to "multiplication".

Comment: Ok, I just do not fully understand it. like what do you mean by affine? what is $M$?

Comment: what is the conjugate transpose of a complex number? or this is a typo in the question?

Comment: No typo. The terminology can be easily looked for on the internet. Please search by yourself before asking.

Comment: Ok, what is the inverse then of my function? what is your $M$?

Comment: I googled it and did not find it for a complex number as it is used here

Comment: It is for complex matrices as clearly said in the exercise. The variable $M$ is an element of $\cal M$ as defined in the answer.  Please read carefully before asking. Also it seems that you lack basic knowledge of math and should consider going back to that before attacking such problems.

Comment: No the domain of the given function is a complex number not a complex matrix

Comment: Please read carefully the statement. This applies to the embedding $M_n(\mathbb C) \to M_n(M_2(\mathbb R)) \cong M_{2n}(\mathbb R)$, so this makes perfect sense. Also refrain to ask questions all the time take the time to think about the problem to figure out things by yourself.

Comment: I can not see how the complex number $x + iy$ can be considered as $M_n(\mathbb C)$ .... could you explain this please?

Comment: I am sorry but it is nowhere said that. However, we have that $\mathbb{C}=M_1(\mathbb{C})$ but this is of no use here.

Comment: If this is not what did you intend to say ... what did you want to say by your comment before last?